# Ruby on Rails - Chartkick - Highcharts drilldown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, chartkick

I have been playing around with the chartkick gem using highcharts.js and was wondering if anyone had been able to get drilldowns to work. If so what options did you pass in to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown
```

Hope it helps you .

Comment: Thanks. With ruby on rails and the chartkick gem would you just pass in the options as like ```library: { drilldown: { series: [{etc}] } }``` ?

Comment: On idea about it (ruby ) but you can use directly this example, Please accept it answer if it helps you .

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you mean.